# how to update NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, xcode4, nsmutabledictionary

I have

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutDic;
```

its loaded with some values from other `NSMutableDictionary`
from an alert i am trying to update its value

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    [self.mutDic setValue:[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text] forKey:@"lname"];
}
```

but i am getting this exception

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
```

how we can update dictionary ?

Comment: the crash log says your dictionary isn't mutable. Can you show us how you alloc/init the dictionary ?

Comment: if you have a `copy` in your @property replace it with `retain` or `strong`. copy always creates immutable objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same exception before even though my dictionary was mutable.  
Let me explain my scenario to you, may be it will help :
I had `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableDictionary`,

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
dict = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

`[dict setObject:@"" forKey:@""];` <-- it was crashing on this line...

so I changed my code as below,

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
```

it worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

found out the exception problem, but not solved fully

on load i need to take values from other dictionary for that the method i used was wrong, i just assign oldDic to mutDic, i changed to

```
self.mutDic = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:manager.oldDic] retain];
```

their initialized it by

```
self.oldDic = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"F Name",@"fname",@"L Name",@"lname", nil ]retain];
```

that solved the exception